# Sort band names

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

## Challenge description

You have a music library with many tracks recorded by many bands, each of which has a name, like `Queen`, `Aerosmith`, `Sunny Day Real Estate`, `The Strokes` . When an audio player displays your library alphabetically by band name, it usually skips the `The` part, as many band names start with `The`, making it easier to navigate through your media collection. In this challenge, given a list (array) of strings, you need to sort it that way (that is, omitting the `The` word at the beginning of the name). You can either write a method or a full working program.

## Sample inputs / outputs

```
[Queen, Aerosmith, Sunny Day Real Estate, The Strokes] -> [Aerosmith, Queen, The Strokes, Sunny Day Real Estate]
[The Ramones, The Cure, The Pixies, The Roots, The Animals, Enrique Iglesias] -> [The Animals, The Cure, Enrique Iglesias, The Pixies, The Ramones, The Roots]
[The The, The They, Thermodynamics] -> [The The, Thermodynamics, The They]
```

## Notes / Edge cases

- Sorting lexicographically is case insensitive, so `The Police`, `The police` and `the police` are all equivalent,
- Your algorithm should only omit the first `the` word, so bands named `The The` or `The The Band` are sorted normally by the second `the`,
- A band named `The` (a three letter word) is sorted normally (no skipping),
- Order of two bands having the same name, one of which starts with `the` (like `The Police` and `Police`) is undefined,
- You can assume that if a band's name consists of more than one word, they are separated by a single space character. You don't need to handle leading or trailing whitespaces,
- All input strings match `[A-Za-z0-9 ]*`, that is they will consist only of lower- and uppercase letters of English alphabet, digits and space characters,
- Remember that this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so make your code as short as possible!

Comment: Do numeral-only names come before or after alphabetical?

Comment: Numeral-only strings come first

Comment: What is the sort order of `The` and `The The`? ( Most answers would probably need to change if it is anything other than undefined )

Comment: how about Los Lobos?

Comment: The The is a real band by the way. (along with The Who, The What, The Where, The When, The Why, and The How)

Comment: If the input had a lowercase `the` but output an uppercase `The`, would this be acceptable?

Comment: Similar to the "the" / "the the" case, What is the sorting order of "red blues" and "the red blues"?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills: They are the same in this case, so the order is undefined

Comment: @njzk2: It's sorted by "Los", since it doesn't start with "the"

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan: Sure

Comment: @JanDvorak: Same as "The" and "The The" case, they are treated the same way lexicographically, so the order is undefined.

Comment: [`the pAper chAse`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paper_Chase_(band)) is a good edge test case

Comment: Probably want an example that actually uses lowercase letters.

Answer (score 7):

### Python, <s>56</s> <s>62</s> 64 bytes

```
lambda b:sorted(b,key=lambda x:(x,x[4:])[x.lower()[:4]=='the '])
```

[Try it](https://repl.it/CilL/1)

Thanks to @Chris H for pointing out that `lstrip()` was not handling `The The` correctly, since the strip was blasting all matching characters and sorting it as a blank string, and @manatwork for finding the flaw in using `replace()`. The new version should work.

Old version:

```
lambda b:sorted(b,key=lambda x:x.lower().lstrip('the '))
```

Comment: I'm not convinced.  Adding "The animals" to the last list gives `['The The', 'The', 'The Animals', 'Thermodynamics', 'The They']`.  The 2nd edge case suggest sit should be ['The Animals', 'The The', 'The', 'Thermodynamics', 'The They'] (or swap the 2nd and 3rd items).  A little fiddling suggests the space inside `strip('the ')` is being ignored - try `for x in ['The The', 'The They', 'Thermodynamics', 'The', 'The Animals']: print (x.lower().strip('the '))`

Comment: That `replace()` is not much better: `'what the snake'.replace('the ','',1)` results `'what snake'`.

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>32</s> 28 bytes

```
ç^The /dwA_
:sort
ç_/$xIThe
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w6deVGhlIC9kd0FfCjpzb3J0CsOnXy8keElUaGUg&input=VGhlIFJhbW9uZXMKUmFkaW9oZWFkClRoZSBDdXJlClRoZSBQaXhpZXMKVGhlIFJvb3RzClRoZSBBbmltYWxzCkVucmlxdWUgSWdsZXNpYXM)

*Note to self: Make an abbreviation for `:sort` so that I don't need 6 whole bytes for a single command!*

Explanation:

```
ç^The /     "On every line starting with 'The ',
       dw   "Delete a word
         A_ "And (A)ppend an underscore '_'

:sort       "Sort all lines alphabetically

ç_/         "On every line containing an underscore,
   $x       "Delete the last character
     IThe   "And prepened 'The '
```

Comment: Not familiar with V, but it seems this one works fine without the asterisks. Is this coincidence with the input, or actually unneeded?

Comment: @kirkpatt Good idea! That *almost* works, but not quite. For example, with [this input](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w61eVGhlIMKoLsKpL8KxXwo6c29ydArDrcKoLsKpXy9UaGUgwrE&input=VGhlIFJhbW9uZXMKUmFkaW9oZWFkClRoZSBDdXJlClRoZSBQaXhpZXMKVGhlIFJvb3RzClRoZSBBbmltYWxzCkVucmlxdWUgSWdsZXNpYXM) it incorrectly puts "Radiohead" after "The Ramones" and "The Roots". However, that gives me an idea...

Comment: What happens if `the` is in all lowercase, like `the pAper chAse`?

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 34 bytes

The trailing linefeed is significant.

```
%`^
$';
T`L`l`.+;
m`^the 

O`
.+;
```

I/O is one band per line.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JWBeCiQnOwpUYExgbGAuKzsKbWBedGhlIAoKT2AKLis7Cg&input=UXVlZW4KQWVyb3NtaXRoClN1bm55IERheSBSZWFsIEVzdGF0ZQpUaGUgU3Ryb2tlcwpUaGUgUmFtb25lcwpUaGUgQ3VyZQpUaGUgUGl4aWVzClRoZSBSb290cwpUaGUgQW5pbWFscwpFbnJpcXVlIElnbGVzaWFzClRoZSBUaGUKVGhlIFRoZXkKVGhlcm1vZHluYW1pY3M)

#### Explanation

```
%`^
$';
```

Duplicate each line, using `;` as a separator.

```
T`L`l`.+;
```

Turn everything in front of a `;` to lower case.

```
m`^the
```

Remove any `the`s that appear at the beginning of a line.

```
O`
```

Sort the lines.

```
.+;
```

Remove the beginnings of the lines which we used for sorting.

Comment: Couldn't you pack the first 3 Steps into a single step? Like in PCRE: s/`(?i:the )?(.*)`/`\L$1\E;$0`/

Comment: @Falco .NET doesn't support case changes in substitution strings and I haven't yet added them to Retina's custom replacer either.

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, 16 bytes

```
.#l1D"the ".^4*>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.%23l1D%22the+%22.%5E4%2a%3E&input=%5B%22Queen%22%2C+%22Aerosmith%22%2C+%22Sunny+Day+Real+Estate%22%2C+%22The+Strokes%22%5D)

```
.#                - sort_by(V, input)
  l1              -  i = i.lower()
      "the ".^    -   i.startswith("the ")
              I   -  if ^:
               4> -   i[4:]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 52 bytes

*-13 byte thanks to @manatwork*
*-1  byte thanks to @msh210*

```
sub f{lc pop=~s/^the //ri}print sort{f($a)cmp f$b}<>
```

One band per line as input, and so is the output.

The implementation is quite straight forward : the program prints the list of bands, sorted with the help of a custom function (`f`) which returns the lower case band name without the eventual leading `the` .

Comment: Is shorter with substitution instead of matching: `sub f{lc$_[0]=~s/^the //ir}`.

Comment: 1 byte shorter indeed, thanks.

Comment: Actually I counted either 2 or 3 bytes shorter: no need for both the parenthesis around `lc`'s parameter and the `i` flag in substitution. Or have you met a test case where that not works?

Comment: Thinking again, the amount of command line options could also be reduced if you take each band name on separate line: `perl -e 'sub f{lc$_[0]=~s/^the //ri}print sort{f($a)cmp f$b}<>' <<< $'Queen\nAerosmith\nSunny Day Real Estate\nThe Strokes'`.

Comment: Oh right, I added the parenthesis because `=~` as a higher precedence than `lc`. But the `lc` is done after the regex so it's ok. But then the `i` flag is needed if I'm not mistaken. Great idea taking the bands name on separated lines.

Comment: Save three bytes: `lc pop` instead of `lc$_[0]`, and `say` instead of `print`. (The latter requires `-M5.01`, which is free.) Tested in Strawberry 5.20.2 with only the first test case from the question.

Comment: Right about the `pop`, thanks. About the `say` I thought of it, but it adds a trailing empty line, so I didn't want to use it...

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>66</s> <s>72</s> 69 bytes

```py
lambda x:sorted(x,key=lambda a:a[4*(a.lower()[:4]=='the '):].lower())
```

Uses Python's `sorted` method with the `key` keyword argument to sort by the name minus "The". This is a lambda; to call it, give it a name by putting `f=` in front.

Now with extra case insensitivity!

Comment: It doesn't meet the case insensitivity requirement, though... A band name can start with `the `, in which case this method won't work properly.

Comment: @shooqie Oh, I didn't see that requirement. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```
$args|sort{$_-replace'^the '}
```

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @MathiasRJessen*

Input is via command-line arguments. Sorts the original names based on the results of the script block `{...}` that performs a regex `-replace` to strip out the leading (case-insensitive) `"the "`.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sort-band-names.ps1 'the Ramones' 'The cure' 'The Pixies' 'The Roots' 'the Animals' 'Enrique Iglesias'
the Animals
The cure
Enrique Iglesias
The Pixies
the Ramones
The Roots

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sort-band-names.ps1 'The The' 'The They' 'Thermodynamics'
The The
Thermodynamics
The They

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sort-band-names.ps1 'THE STOOGES' 'The Strokes' 'The The' 'the they' 'the band' 'STP'
the band
THE STOOGES
STP
The Strokes
The The
the they
```

Comment: `-replace` is case-insensitive by default, `'^the '` will suffice for the pattern

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @ValueInk See Mathias' comment about case insensitivity and the final example I added.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript/ECMAScript 6 <s>93</s> 70 bytes

**70** *Thanks to Neil and Downgoat for advice*

```
B=>B.sort((a,b)=>R(a).localeCompare(R(b)),R=s=>s.replace(/^the /i,''))
```

*Readable Version for the 70-byte variant*

```
let sortBandNames = (bandNames) => {
    let stripThe = (name) => name.replace(/^the /i, '');
    let compareFunc = (a, b) => stripThe(a).localeCompare(stripThe(b));
    return bandNames.sort(compareFunc)
};
```

**93**

```
f=B=>{R=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/the /,'');return B.sort((a,b)=>R(a).localeCompare(R(b)))}
```

*Readable Version for the 93-byte variant*

```
let sortBandNames = (bandNames) => {
    let stripThe = (name) => name.toLowerCase().replace(/the /, '');
    let compareFunc = (a, b) => stripThe(a).localeCompare(stripThe(b));
    return bandNames.sort(compareFunc)
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't that regexp have a `^` in it? Also, localeCompare is case insensitive on my system, so I didn't need the `toLowerCase`, just an `/i` flag on the regexp. Finally you can golf this as follows: `B=>B.sort((a,b)=>...,R=s=>...)` - `sort` ignores the extra parameter that sets `R`.

Comment: Where in the regex would ^ go? That would be a negation and the the expression is supposed to match and erase "the ". I'll try using locale compare without the lower-case conversion.

Comment: @Pandacoder the `^` shuold go at the beginning of the regex

Comment: @Downgoat From testing all of the given cases, and a few cases I came up with specifically intending to break the RegEx, with or without the ^ I get no change in behavior, only an extra character that doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @Pandacoder that doesn't make it valid. the ^ is an anchor which requires the "the" to be at the beginning per the spec

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Didn't think of sticking "The" in the middle.

Comment: Updated to include that caret.

Comment: You can remove the f= as it's ok to return an anonymous function. Also you may be able to save some bytes by mapping to lowercase&replacing the the and use .sort() which is lexicographic by default

Comment: @Downgoat What do you mean by mapping to lowercase (just to make sure, you're looking at the 72/70-byte variant, not the 93/91-byte one)?

Comment: I meant `a=>a.map(i=>i.toLowerCase().replace(/^the /,'')).sort();` but just relized why that doesn't work you can still remove `f=` and make it just `B=>B.sort((a,b)=>R(a).localeCompare(R(b)),R=s=>s.replace(/^the /i,''))` to save 2 bytes

Comment: I feel like there is a way to use map, just as part of the comparator function, but I don't know how to get the lexicographical difference of a two-string array easily. I'll strip the ```f=``` though.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 42 bytes

```
->a{a.sort_by{|s|s.upcase.sub /^THE /,''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Ciq3)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 26 bytes

```perl6
*.sort({fc S:i/^'the '//})
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
# ｢*｣ is the input to this Whatever lambda
*.sort(

  # sort based on the return value of this Block lambda
  {
    fc # foldcase the following

    # string replace but not in-place
    S
      :ignorecase
      /
        # at the start of the string
        ^

        # match ｢the ｣
        'the '

      # replace with nothing
      //
  }
)
```

#### Test:

```perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
  « Queen Aerosmith 'Sunny Day Real Estate' 'The Strokes' »
    => « Aerosmith Queen 'The Strokes' 'Sunny Day Real Estate' »,
  « 'The Ramones' 'The Cure' 'The Pixies' 'The Roots' 'The Animals' 'Enrique Iglesias' »
    => « 'The Animals' 'The Cure' 'Enrique Iglesias' 'The Pixies' 'The Ramones' 'The Roots' »,
  « 'The The' 'The They' Thermodynamics »
    => « 'The The' Thermodynamics 'The They' »,
);

# give it a lexical name for clarity
my &band-sort = *.sort({fc S:i/^'the '//});

plan +@tests;

for @tests -> ( :key(@input), :value(@expected) ) {
  is-deeply band-sort(@input), @expected, @expected.perl;
}
```

```perl6
1..3
ok 1 - ("Aerosmith", "Queen", "The Strokes", "Sunny Day Real Estate")
ok 2 - ("The Animals", "The Cure", "Enrique Iglesias", "The Pixies", "The Ramones", "The Roots")
ok 3 - ("The The", "Thermodynamics", "The They")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8, 178 bytes

```
void q(String[]s){java.util.Arrays.sort(s,(a,b)->(a.toLowerCase().startsWith("the ")?a.substring(4):a).compareToIgnoreCase(b.toLowerCase().startsWith("the ")?b.substring(4):b));}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void sort(String[] bands) {
    java.util.Arrays.sort(bands, (a, b) -> 
        (a.toLowerCase().startsWith("the ") ? a.substring(4) : a).compareToIgnoreCase(
            b.toLowerCase().startsWith("the ") ? b.substring(4) : b
        )
    );
}
```

Call as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] bands = {"The Strokes", "Queen", "AC/DC", "The Band", "Cage the Elephant", "cage the elephant"};
    sort(bands); // or q(bands) in the golfed version
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(bands));
}
```

Comment: I know you've answered this almost a year ago, but you can golf a few things. Since you state you use Java 8, you can change `void q(String[]s){...}` to `s->{...}`. And you can change both `(x.toLowerCase().startsWith("the ")?x.substring(4):x)` with `x.replaceFirst("(?i)the ","")`. So the total becomes: [`s->{java.util.Arrays.sort(s,(a,b)->a.replaceFirst("(?i)the ","").compareToIgnoreCase(b.replaceFirst("(?i)the ","")));}` - **118 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/ycasf8t9)

Comment: Neat trick with the replaceFirst. When I answered this I had been told a few times on other answers that `s->{ ... }` wasn't allowed and I had to have a full method signature with types and whatnot. I don't know if that's changed since then.

Comment: Not sure about back then, but these days it's allowed and used by close to everyone golfing in Java or C# .NET.

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + coreutils, 44 bytes

```sh
sed '/^the /I!s,^,@ ,'|sort -dk2|sed s,@\ ,,
```

**Explanation:** the input and output format is one band per line

```sh
sed '/^the /I!s,^,@ ,'   # prepend '@ ' to each line not starting with 'the ', case
                         #insensitive. This adds a temporary field needed by sort.
sort -dk2                # sort in ascending dictionary order by 2nd field onward
sed s,@\ ,,              # remove the temporary field
```

**Test run (using a here-document with EOF as the end marker):**

```sh
./sort_bands.sh << EOF
> Queen
> Aerosmith
> Sunny Day Real Estate
> The Strokes
> EOF
```

**Output:**

```sh
Aerosmith
Queen
The Strokes
Sunny Day Real Estate
```

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 18 bytes

Well now that I realized this is possible, I'm kinda embarrassed by my 26 byte V answer, especially since V is supposed to be shorter than vim. But this is pretty much a builtin.

```
:sor i/\(The \)*/<CR>
```

Explanation (straight from vim help):

```
                            *:sor* *:sort*
:[range]sor[t][!] [b][f][i][n][o][r][u][x] [/{pattern}/]
            Sort lines in [range].  When no range is given all
            lines are sorted.

            With [i] case is ignored.

            When /{pattern}/ is specified and there is no [r] flag
            the text matched with {pattern} is skipped, so that
            you sort on what comes after the match.
            Instead of the slash any non-letter can be used.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>216</s> <s>212</s> 135 + 5 (`qsort`) = <s>221</s> <s>217</s> 140 bytes

```
M(void*a,void*b){char*A,*B;A=*(char**)a;B=*(char**)b;A=strcasestr(A,"The ")?A+4:A;B=strcasestr(B,"The ")?B+4:B;return strcasecmp(A,B);}
```

Well, I finally got around to finishing this in `C`. Golfing tips are very much appreciated.

In this submission, `M` is the comparison function to be supplied to [`qsort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Array-Sort-Function.html#Array-Sort-Function). Therefore, to invoke this, you must use `qsort` in the format `qsort(argv++,argc--,8,M)` where `argv` contains the command-line arguments and `argc` is the number of arguments provided.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TU89T8MwEJ2bX2EFIcWJgxiYcAuyBWMHKBswuI6TODR2sZ1IpcrPZjZ2iqDT3fu4d3e8bDj3F1Lx3VAJsLSukvqqvUvOKSNVEzi/zkYtq5yhuWzhkbfM5ATlFJNVns0ohwzTf7ANSgjgzIpQMoLSl1aAFN6T4uaWBOeZSP9EGkSKjXCDUeDXwft9GKcQT14qB3omVRYbZhqOTttiP0JwTBafVhuXRVgUKDrKEln5JXR9OgyiNcTJotZmzuhW17hbRh/uimJOWOzD167O0kv7ptKYMb5273FoSibvnwYhlCfCaNtL1/rNoNQBPLADeBZsBx6tY074@M7GGf0h7LfSJWe8FT8)

Comment: [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZA9T8MwEIbn5Fe4QUj@isqIFDqkgrEDlA0YjDk3SYlTbKdKE@W3Gzvq0ulOzz3vO5zMD1J6f/cDqtaARjwQOrDVyjojhYUwMB149l4Byki6w7V2lJZ8GVsyGXC90ehqy/aER1wSPuItIcWssODfJLqimP5sZ1wE/JHvwtEHjlpR69iJhDlILithKI37maApTdbraygAxnh08pzbeoRO4UUmsSpVt0YgierM0ttsHormKfKiYWxpTU4mXBTO7u2nzmLm/NF8xdCczt6/9gDal2A629au8vte6wt6Fhf0BuIXvVgnHPj4kL0z3RHsPw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 96 bytes

```nim
import algorithm,strutils,future
x=>x.sortedByIt toLower it[4*int(it.toLower[0..3]=="the ")..^0]
```

<sup>Those `import`s take up so many bytes `:|`</sup>

A translation of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87456/56755).

This is an anonymous procedure; to use it, it must be passed into a testing procedure. Here's a full program you can use for testing:

```nim
import algorithm,strutils,future
proc test(x: seq[string] -> seq[string]) =
 echo x(@["The The", "The They", "Thermodynamics"]) # Substitute your input here
test(x=>x.sortedByIt toLower it[4*int(it.toLower[0..3]=="the ")..^0])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
tk'^the '[]YX2$S
```

Input format is (each line corresponds to a test case)

```
{'Queen', 'Aerosmith', 'Sunny Day Real Estate', 'The Strokes'} 
{'The Ramones', 'The Cure', 'The Pixies', 'The Roots', 'The Animals', 'Enrique Iglesias'}
{'The The', 'The They', 'Thermodynamics'}
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dGsnXnRoZSAnW11ZWDIkUw&input=eydRdWVlbicsICdBZXJvc21pdGgnLCAnU3VubnkgRGF5IFJlYWwgRXN0YXRlJywgJ1RoZSBTdHJva2VzJ30g)

#### Explanation

```
t        % Implicitly input cell array of strings. Push another copy
k        % Convert to lowercase
'^the '  % String to be used as regex pattern: matches initial 'the '
[]       % Empty array
YX       % Regex replacement: replace initial 'the ' in each string by empty array
2$S      % Sort input according to the modified cell array. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 84 bytes

```
import Data.List
p(t:'h':'e':' ':s)|elem t"Tt"=s
p s=s
sortBy(\a b->p a`compare`p b)
```

Call with

```
sortBy(\a b->p a`compare`p b)["The The", "The They", "Thermodynamics"]
```

Testcase:

```
let s = sortBy(\a b->p a`compare`p b)
and[s["Queen", "Aerosmith", "Sunny Day Real Estate", "The Strokes"]==["Aerosmith", "Queen", "The Strokes", "Sunny Day Real Estate"],s["The Ramones", "The Cure", "The Pixies", "The Roots", "The Animals", "Enrique Iglesias"]==["The Animals", "The Cure", "Enrique Iglesias", "The Pixies", "The Ramones", "The Roots"],s["The The", "The They", "Thermodynamics"]==["The The", "Thermodynamics", "The They"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 139 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;System.Collections.IEnumerable S(string[] l)=> l.OrderBy(b=>(b.ToLower().StartsWith("the ")?b.Substring(4):b).ToLower());
```

[Try online!](http://csharppad.com/gist/7f2a6e59f3525c4e81fe1068956400a4)

Without counting the usings the answer would be 102 bytes.

Comment: I believe you can ignore the final `ToLower()` due to the case-insensitive requirement

Comment: Also you can make it an anonymous function which should save some bytes:

Comment: `l=>l.OrderBy(b=>(b.ToLower().StartsWith("the ")?b.Substring(4):b));` For 67 bytes and then you need to add on the `using System.Linq;` too

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: I need the second `ToLower` because of the case-insensitive requirement. Otherwise the order would be case-sensitive.

Comment: Okay the point about converting it to an anonymous function still stands though

Answer (score 0):

**BASH, 64 Bytes**

```
sed 's/^the / /;s/^The /    /'|sort -fb|sed 's/^ /the /;s/^ /The /'
```

Input: stdin, one band per line.
Output: stdout

Note: The second replacements (s/^The/  / and s/^   /The /) use the tab character, so they don't always copy/paste correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, <s>36</s> 33 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x(<)@[x;(&)x like"[Tt]he *";4_]}
```

**Example:**

```
q){x(<)@[x;(&)x like"[Tt]he *";4_]}("Queen";"Aerosmith";"Sunny Day Real Estate";"The Strokes";"the Eagles")
"Aerosmith"
"the Eagles"
"Queen"
"The Strokes"
"Sunny Day Real Estate"
```

**Explanation:**

Strip out any "[Tt]he " from each input string, sort this list, then sort the original list based on the indexing of the sorted list.

```
{x iasc @[x;where x like "[Tt]he *";4_]} / ungolfed solution
{                                      } / lambda function
        @[x;                       ;  ]  / apply function to x at indices
                                    4_   / 4 drop, remove first 4 items
            where x like "[Tt]he *"      / where the input matches 'The ...' or 'the ...'
   iasc                                  / returns sorted indices
 x                                       / index into original list at these indices
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 27 bytes

```
vyð¡RD¤…TheQsgα£Rðý})‚øí{ø¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/rPLwhkMLg1wOLXnUsCwkIzWwOP3cxkOLgw5vOLy3VvNRw6zDOw6vrT6849CS//@jlYAKFIBYSUcBxqyEsoty81Mq8xJzM5OLlWIB)

#### Explanation

```
vyð¡RD¤…TheQsgα£Rðý})‚øí{ø¤   Argument l
v                 }           For each y in l, do:
 yð¡                            Split y on space
    RD                          Reverse and duplicate
      ¤…TheQ                    Last element equals "The" (true = 1, false = 0)
            sgα                 Absolute difference with length of array
               £                Get elements from index 0 to calculated difference
                R               Reverse
                 ðý             Join on space
                    )‚øí      Pair each element with original
                        {ø¤   Sort and get the original band name
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 34 bytes

```
{it.sort{it.toLowerCase()-'the '}}
```

41% my answer is `.toLowerCase()`, kill me now.

---

## Output

When running...

```
({it.sort{it.toLowerCase()-'the '}})(['The ramones','The Cure','The Pixies','The Roots','The Animals','Enrique Iglesias'])
```

The result is...

`[The Animals, The Cure, Enrique Iglesias, The Pixies, The ramones, The Roots]`

With no debug or error output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
ñ_v r`^e
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8V92IHJgXpBlIA==&input=WyJUaGUgUmFtb25lcyIsIlRoZSBDdXJlIiwiVGhlIFBpeGllcyIsIlRoZSBSb290cyIsIlRoZSBBbmltYWxzIiwiRW5yaXF1ZSBJZ2xlc2lhcyIsIlF1ZWVuIiwiQWVyb3NtaXRoIiwiU3VubnkgRGF5IFJlYWwgRXN0YXRlIiwiVGhlIFN0cm9rZXMiLCJUaGUgVGhlIiwiVGhlIFRoZXkiLCJUaGVybW9keW5hbWljcyIsInRoZSBwQXBlciBjaEFzZV0=)

Answer (score -2):

## Java <s>176</s> 158 bytes

```
public String[]sort(String[]names){
  for(int i=-1;++i<names.length;)
    if(names[i].startsWith("(The |the )"))
      names[i]=names[i].substring(4);
  return Arrays.sort(names,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
  }
```

Main Function

```
public static void main(String[]args){
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  List<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
  while(!(String h = s.nextLine).equalsIgnoreCase("~")){
    list.add(h);
  }
System.out.println(sort(list.toArray(newString[0]))
```

);
    }

Golfed sort function:

```
String[]s(String[]n){for(int i=-1;++i<n.length;)if(n[i].startsWith("(The |the )"))n[i]=n[i].substring(4);return Arrays.sort(n,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);}
```

> Thanks to @raznagul for saving 18 bytes

Comment: Doesn't work if a name starts with `the `. The sort should be case insensitive.

Comment: This won't work at all... Strings are immutable. You want to do `public String[]sort(String[]names){
  for(int i=-1;++i<names.length;)
  names[i]=names[i].replaceFirst("(the|The)", "");
  return Arrays.sort(names,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
  }` Since the and The should work, and strings a immutable

Comment: Fixed that, but find me one band that starts with a small "the "

Comment: I'm not very good at Java so I might be wrong. But couldn't `.replaceFirst...` be replaced with `.substring(4) `?

Comment: Yes that's right. I thought replace will edit the String but doesn't. So i missed that while editing last time.

Comment: `Arrays.sort` returns type void

Comment: @RomanGräf [`the pAper chAse`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paper_Chase_(band))